# Maintain order of records after soft delete

Tags: php, mysql, soft-delete

I have built a soft delete system for a table which contains the following columns:

```
 - ID (Auto increments from 1) 
 - Category 
 - Title 
 - Is_Deleted 
 - Timestamp (Created)
```

Sample Data (3 rows):

```
1   Department  Dd1x1  0  2014-10-24 18:41:54   
2   Logistics   L2x14  0  2014-10-24 16:55:27
3   Transit     T4y3   0  2014-10-24 17:09:27
```

**The soft deletes are set to work when updating a record as well (Business Requirement).** So if I update category "Department" to "Department Data", I do so with :

```
UPDATE categories_latest SET Is_Deleted = 1 WHERE ID = 1;
INSERT INTO categories_latest(Category, Title, Is_Deleted) VALUES('Department Data', 'Dd1x1', 0);
```

The code itself works fine, but when I display this data in the Frontend, **it changes the order of the records, due to being ordered by ID**. Only way I can think of to get around this, is to have an extra column with an "Order" variable of some sort, which the query will have to sort before retrieving.

Is there an easier way to handle the problem, and allow for the order of the records to remain unchanged?

Comment: Could you provide an example how it is ordered ?

Comment: Just a simple select statement which (by default) orders by the ID, is what I am using now! I can add in the code if it would help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding new record you can just save your last value to some other column. It wont create redundant records, also order will be same.

Comment: This was my first idea, but several soft deletes down the line, there is no clear line connecting the current value and the oldest value. Only way to navigate would be to do a string of select statements, slowly going back one step at a time till I find the one I need.

Correct me if I'm wrong and there is another way past that problem, please! :)

Comment: Then only thing you can do is maintain relationships, like linked list. Primary key of "Department" will be maintained with "Department Data"when it is modified its pk will be maintained with next value and so on.

Comment: I got that from your answer, but as I pointed out, this becomes inefficient after 4 or 5 changes. :)

Comment: I know. if you want to maintain order with soft delete you need to update current record and insert old record as new row.

Comment: Thought about that as well. This would cause the `timestamp` column to render incorrect information since it would have to act as `CURRENT ON UPDATE CURRENT` for the "Main" row which is updated, and "CURRENT" for the remaining ones.... If the records were stored separately however, that could work. I will check that out.